# coherence between $\mathbb{Z}_N, \mathbb{Z}_N^* $ and $ \phi(N)$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I have a theoretical question concerning the following task in an exam.

I have given a Number $N \in \mathbb{N}$

### Question

The question is what is the relationship between $\mathbb{Z}_N,\mathbb{Z}_N^*  $ and $\phi(N)$

I know that $\mathbb{Z}_N$ contains all integer numbers to $N$, and that $\mathbb{Z}_N^*$ is the representation of all numbers to $N$ in a multiplicative Group, which basically means that all numbers to $N$ are associative and there is an identity element as well as an inverse element for $*$. But how is the realtionship with $\phi$.

In don't really understand what a correct answer to this question would look like.

### Edit

So as far as I understood is the relation the following:

$\mathbb{Z}_N$ contains all the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_N^*$ and  $\mathbb{Z}_N^*$ contains all the elements of $\phi(N)$. Which can be written like this:

$\phi(N) \in \mathbb{Z}_N^* \in \mathbb{Z}_N$ ?

Comment: I have no idea what ${\mathbb Z}_{-5}$ means. Perhaps you want $N > 0$.

Comment: actually there was a mistake: $N \in \mathbb N$ is right. But I can't see any $\mathbb Z _-5$in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}_N^*$ consists of the (classes of) all numbers that are coprime with $N$.

$\mathbb{Z}_N^*$ has $\phi(N)$ elements.

$\mathbb{Z}_N$ and $\mathbb{Z}_N^*$ are sets of equivalence classes mod $N$, 
not subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$, but they are frequently represented as such, which can be confusing.

Comment: okay and because $\mathbb{Z}$ contains all Elements of $\mathbb{Z}_N^*$ the relation is complete? So the relationship between all these is that each of them starting from left to right (if we would write them next to each other) contains the elemtents of each other?

Comment: $\phi(N)$ doesn't contain anything. It is a number, not a set. It is the number of elements of ${\bf Z}_N^*$.